# Get calling function name in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to get calling function name in Clojure. Something like combination of macro's implicit variable `&form` and `*file*` var. I need to get or infer function name from those variable or something else if possible. Will have to be non platform specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function already exists [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  There are two functions that are thin wrappers over `tupelo.misc/stacktrace-info`

- [fn-info](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.197/api/tupelo.misc#fn-info)
- [fn-info-caller](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.197/api/tupelo.misc#fn-info-caller)

They return a map of info about the current function (or its parent), like:

```
       {:ns-name     'demo.core'
        :fn-name     'add2'
        :class-name  'demo.core$add2'
        :file-name   'core.clj'
        :line-num    57
        :method-name 'invokeStatic' }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to use the platform-specific

`(-> (Throwable.) .getStackTrace)` in java

and

`(-> (js/Error.) .-stack)` in js and work it out from those sadly.

I don't think there's anything platform agnostic.